# Why emacs --batch Org-Mode pdf export doesn't work as expected?

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp, batch-processing, org-mode

I'm trying to `org-export-as-pdf` an org file in batch mode (org version > 8).

```
$ emacs --batch --file test.org -f org-export-as-pdf-and-open
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/preview-latex.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50css-mode.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50html-helper-mode.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50org-mode.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50pymacs.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-docutils.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-mode.el (source)...
OVERVIEW
Loading vc-hg...
Exporting to PDF...
Exporting to LaTeX...
Applying style hooks...
Applying style hooks... done
```

Eventually:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: org-export-latex-packages-alist
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run Emacs interactively, open `test.org` and execute `org-export-as-pdf`?

Comment: Interactively does work. That's why i think my need is to load some environment vars or elisp script.

Comment: ...seems like LaTeX doesn't get any mandatory `\usepackages{}` i think.

Comment: Apparently `--batch` implies `-q`, so your own Emacs configuration is not being used. If you try adding `-l ~/.emacs.d/init.el` immediately after the `--batch` argument (or `-l ~/.emacs` if your configuration is located there), does it work?

Comment: I thought only -Q implies to not load init.el! But I haven't any init.el or .emacs (i'm on vanilla debian)... As you can see my site-start scripts loads...

Comment: Yes, `--batch` loads the site configuration, but not the user configuration. You don't have any personal configuration at all? In that case, I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: As seen in `50org-mode.el` i tried: `emacs --batch --file test.org --eval "(require 'org-install)" -f org-export-as-pdf-and-open` but it didn't work.

Comment: Tried [to add](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-and-sectioning.html#Header-and-sectioning) `#+LATEX_CLASS: article \ #+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper] \ #+LATEX_HEADER:` in .org file... noway